# integrating .Net Framework with IIS on windows server 2008 r2

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I am deploying a website using .net framework 4.5 on a 2008r2 server, I installed the .Net framework on the box, but i do not see it anywhere in Server Manager (was looking under features) the system had .net 3.5 on it already, and from what i have read it should have installed with all the options for that version. however my webpages throw exceptions of `unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'` on the `<compilation targetFramework="4.5">` line making me suspect there is some error registering the install.
I have run aspnet_regiis and ServiceModelReg, I have also tried the .net framework repair tool to no avail. I feel as though I am missing a step some-ware.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Have you checked if the Framework-Version of the AppPool is set properly?

Comment: unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework' is the exception

Comment: @bassfader i lloked in the application pool and saw that it is showing 4.0 there, i would assume this is correct as the 4.5 is just an upgrade in place, but i do not have the option to add 4.5 there

Answer (score 1):

You have to run aspnet_regiis to get the new framework installed into IIS.  It's located in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319.  Go to that location in a command window and run this command.

```
aspnet_regiis -ir
```

Comment: Is the application pool using v4.0?

Comment: yes, it is showing 4.0 and 4.0 classic, do i need to install the Multi-Targeting pack?

Comment: Those are just the names of the default application pools.  Which application pool is the site using?  You can check that in Basic Settings for the site.

Answer (score 0):

this seems very odd to me, when I went into the application pool and opened  the asp.netv4.0 default properties it was set to use the .Net Framework version of v2.0, changing that to v4.0 worked